# Firebase DocumentSnapshot.data() returns Object? instead of Map<String, dynamic>

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

The documentation for [the DocumentSnapshot.data()](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase/latest/firebase_firestore/DocumentSnapshot/data.html) says it returns `Map<String, dynamic>`
Nevertheless, the IDE tells me about the error and claims data() returns `Object?`

```
The argument type 'Object?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Map<String, dynamic>'.dart(argument_type_not_assignable)
```

What I am trying to do is the following

```
 factory NoteDto.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$NoteDtoFromJson(json);

  factory NoteDto.fromFirestore(DocumentSnapshot doc) {
    return NoteDto.fromJson(doc.data()).copyWith(id: doc.id);
  }
```

Should I convert somehow `Object?` to `Map<String, dynamic>`?
I looked into `DocumentSnapshot.data()` definition and I see it uses a template `T? data()` and class itself is `abstract class DocumentSnapshot<T extends Object?>`. Now I understand where `Object?` comes from.

How can I ensure I get `Map<String, dynamic>` instead of `Object?` from `DocumentSnapshot.data()` ?

If I change `NoteDto.fromFirestore` to

```
factory NoteDto.fromFirestore(DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> doc) {
```

I still need to convert `Object?` to Map<String, dynamic> at some point, but this time it is `QueryDocumentSnapshot<Object?> doc` in the following call:

```
...
.map((doc) => NoteDto.fromFirestore(doc).toDomain())
...
```

Comment: were you able to solve this? I've got a similar issue with a DataSnapshot Event

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In other places I had functions returning `Future<DocumentReference>` and `CollectionReference`. I had to add types to them like that:

```
Future<DocumentReference<Map<String, dynamic>>>
...
CollectionReference<Map<String, dynamic>>
```

Now, when I receive `QueryDocumentSnapshot doc` in:

```
.map((doc) => NoteDto.fromFirestore(doc).toDomain())
```

its type is `QueryDocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>` instead of `QueryDocumentSnapshot<Object?>` what solves my problem.

Comment: Would this work with a Datasnapshot Event? I'm stuck with a similar scenario as above. Could I get a little more in-depth example with your solution approach please?

Comment: I just added types <Map<String, dynamic>> to variables declaration and then IDE stopped warning me about Object? being assigned to the map.

Comment: Query query = blogPostCollection
        .orderBy('timestamp', descending: true)
        .limit(limit);                                                                                                  
         ( convert the variable declaration  Query to Map<String, dynamic>, and it work)